# curl with --cacert fails on almalinux8 but works on ubuntu

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, curl

We try this:

```
curl -v --cacert  cert.pem https://example.com/path.asmx
```

on ubuntu its working, we're getting:

```
successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: cert.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
```

on almalinux8 it's failing with:

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: cert.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

What can be the cause?

Thanks

Comment: What is the contents of `cert.pem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> * successfully set certificate verify locations:
> *   CAfile: cert.pem
>   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> ```

Since `cert.pem` is probably the same on both invocation the difference is likely in `/etc/ssl/certs`. I would assume that `cert.pem` does not actually contain the trusted root CA used by the server certificate, but that it is inside `/etc/ssl/certs` on one machine but not on the other.

Why the CA is on one machine but not on the other is unknown, might it is maybe caused by different setups of the machines.

> ```
> * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
> * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
> ```

The server asks for a client certificate here. This suggests that your argument of `--cacert cert.pem` might not be intended to provide the trusted root certificate, but instead the client certificate expected by the server. But for this `--cert` and `--key` should be used.

Comment: Perfect. Indeed with --cert instead of --cacert, it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`TLS Alert, unknown CA` means that the certificate authority, the one who issued the certificate, is not known as an authority on the Almalinux machine. This is nothing to do with the distros being different. The issue is simply that whoever issued the certificate is known and authoritative on the Ubuntu machine, and not accepted as authoritative on the Almalinux machine. Perhaps the thing to do is find a different CA, one that the Almalinux machine knows and trusts.

Comment: How do I make the certificate authority known to Almalinux?